# MVC 5 IIS 8.5 securing pdf files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I've been looking around for a solution but can't seem to find one that fits my requirements.
I have an MVC application that is password protected and uses Identity 2.0. There are a lot of PDF files that are stored within the application that I'd only like authenticated users to be able to access.

PDF's are stored in a lot of separate folders, the system has 1000's of cases each of which has it's own Case folder like:

```
/Cases
    /CaseId
        /Letters
            /Letter1.pdf
            /Letter2.pdf
        /Reports
            /Report1.pdf
            /Report2.pdf
```

I have tried using web.config

```
<location path="~/Cases">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

But I think I can't use this as the PDF's are scross multiple subfolders and this will only protect the files within the `/Cases` folder and not the files in subfolders, is that correct?

I've seen that a HttpHandler could be the way to go about it, i've tried:

```
<add name="PDFHandler" verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

But this doesn't seem to work on it's own, do I also need to write something in MVC?

If anyone could let me know the best way to go about this or point me in the direction of a solution please.

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

Web.config

```
  <location path="~/Cases">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Trouble">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"></error>
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/NotAuthorized"></error>
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="PDFHandler" verb="*"
        path="*.pdf"
        type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Nothing, I can still open any .pdf file under the `/Cases` folder.

Comment: What happens if you change `~/Cases` to `Cases`? Does the `Cases` folder exist in the same parent folder where `web.config` lives? Do you have any other `authorization` elements in your `web.config`?

Comment: the 'web.config' is on the root. I've added part of the 'web.config' in my edit above. Should the 'web.config' option work the way I require it to then?

Comment: Nothing happens if I change to `Cases`. The `web.config` and `Cases` folder are both on the root so yes. My `web.config` is above so I guess no I don't have any other `authorization` elements in my `web.config`

Comment: So, to be clear, if you logout of your app you are still able to access a url like http://webservername/cases//1/Letters/Letter1.pdf ?

Comment: Yes, I can still view any .pdf file in any subfolder under `Cases`.

Comment: I just moved a .pdf file to `/Cases/Letter1.pdf` for a test and tried to access that and I got redirected to the `/NotAuthorised` page. So seems that as i thought it doesn't protect subfolders as I can still view `Cases/1/Letters/Letter1.pdf `

Comment: This seemed to do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027024/web-config-deny-access-to-subfolder-recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change to the web.config seemed to do as i wanted in this question [Web.config Deny access to subfolder recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027024/web-config-deny-access-to-subfolder-recursively)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible in your case, but the best way to handle security is to move all your PDF files outside the application directory, and access them only through an action on a controller. This way, you can handle the security in your code, and it will be much more robust than using configuration.